# Need to convert MySQL query to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a table of companies that have events.  I need to create a summary table that shows the active companies by month, meaning how many companies have at least one or more events in every month.  Any company that has an event in a month is considered active.

I was able to do this detailed count table with a summary of active companies as a total at the end, but I can't recreate this in PostgreSQL.

Also this report has all the companies listed that have events, I would also like a report where ONLY the the total is presented.

```
CREATE TABLE mysql_test ( 
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
company VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
my_date DATETIME NOT NULL,  
status VARCHAR(50), 
reg_date TIMESTAMP 
); 


INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('1', 'ABC', '2019/1/1', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('2', 'ABC', '2019/1/1', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('3', 'ABC', '2019/2/2', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('4', 'ABC', '2019/2/2', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('5', 'DEF', '2019/2/2', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('6', 'DEF', '2019/2/2', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('7', 'DEF', '2019/3/3', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('8', 'DEF', '2019/3/3', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('9', 'GHI', '2019/3/3', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('10', 'GHI', '2019/3/3', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('11', 'JKL', '2019/1/1', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('12', 'JKL', '2019/2/2', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('13', 'JKL', '2019/2/2', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
INSERT INTO `mysql_test` (`id`, `company`, `my_date`, `status`, `reg_date`) VALUES ('14', 'JKL', '2019/1/1', 'event', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 

(SELECT company,
        SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 1) as Jan,
        SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 2) as Feb,
        SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 3) as Mar
 FROM mysql_test
 WHERE status = 'Event' AND my_date >= '2019-01-01' AND
       my_date < '2020-10-01'
 GROUP BY company
) UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Total',
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(my_date) = 1 THEN company END) as Jan,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(my_date) = 2 THEN company END) as Feb,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(my_date) = 3 THEN company END) as Mar
FROM mysql_test
WHERE status = 'Event' AND my_date >= '2019-01-01' AND
      my_date < '2020-10-01'
);
```

Comment: Try `pg_chameleon`? (https://pgchameleon.org)

Answer (score 2):

This syntax that is not supported in Postgres:

```
SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 1)
```

In MySQL, conditions return `0` or `1` when evaluated in numeric context, but not in Postgres. Explicit casting from boolean to integer is needed. Also, function `MONTH()` does not exists, you can use the more standard `EXTRACT()`, like so:

```
SUM( (EXTRACT(month from my_date) = 1)::int )
```

Also, it would be better to cast dates for comparison (even if I Postgres would probably do it for you if you don't), so this:

```
my_date >= '2019-01-01'
```

Could be rewritten:

```
my_date >= '2019-01-01'::date
```

Here is a new version for your query:

```
(
    SELECT company,
        SUM( (EXTRACT(month from my_date) = 1)::int ) as Jan,
        SUM( (EXTRACT(month from my_date) = 2)::int ) as Feb,
        SUM( (EXTRACT(month from my_date) = 3)::int ) as Mar
    FROM mysql_test
    WHERE 
        status = 'event' 
        AND my_date >= '2019-01-01'::date 
        AND my_date <  '2020-10-01'::date
 GROUP BY company
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT 
        'Total',
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from my_date) = 1 THEN company END) as Jan,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from my_date) = 2 THEN company END) as Feb,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month from my_date) = 3 THEN company END) as Mar
    FROM mysql_test
    WHERE 
        status = 'event' 
        AND my_date >= '2019-01-01'::date 
        AND my_date < '2020-10-01'::date
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=21f3f487e18cff8c2fb02ab9a364f80d)**:

```
company | jan | feb | mar
:------ | --: | --: | --:
ABC     |   2 |   2 |   0
DEF     |   0 |   2 |   2
GHI     |   0 |   0 |   2
JKL     |   2 |   2 |   0
Total   |   2 |   3 |   2
```

NB: few changes need to be done in the declaration of the table as well, see the db fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using conditional aggregation. By putting the base query into a common table expression, you also don't need to repeat the WHERE clause:

```
with base as (
  select company,  
         count(*) filter (where extract(month from my_date) = 1) as jan,
         count(*) filter (where extract(month from my_date) = 2) as feb,
         count(*) filter (where extract(month from my_date) = 3) as mar
  FROM mysql_test
  WHERE status = 'event' 
    AND my_date >= DATE '2019-01-01' AND my_date < DATE '2020-10-01'
  GROUP BY company
)
select *
from base
union all
select 'Total',
       count(*) filter (where jan > 0),
       count(*) filter (where feb > 0),
       count(*) filter (where mar > 0)
from base;
```

Using your sample data, this returns:

```
company | jan | feb | mar
--------+-----+-----+----
ABC     |   2 |   2 |   0
DEF     |   0 |   2 |   2
GHI     |   0 |   0 |   2
JKL     |   2 |   2 |   0
Total   |   2 |   3 |   2
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=932fc69ebf172293f0f8e20320506b84)